# Disabled RC4 and Qualys still says I have it enabled

Tags: centos, apache-http-server, ssl, openssl, centos-7

I would like some help on my Apache CentOS 7 website. I don't know why it still has RC4 enabled when it is already disabled. Maybe I still have it enabled. So this is my configuration for my web server. (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf)

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder on

SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 \
EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 \
EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"
```

If you could provide me a new code for SSLCipherSuite, that'd be great. Also I wanted to point out that these are the errors I'm receiving on the Qualys SSL Test.

***First Problem***:

[image]

***Second Problem***:

[image]

If anyone can reply to this, I would appreciate it so much!!

Comment: You are missing exclamation marks (`!`) in front of the RC4 bits (RC4 and EECDH+aRSA+RC4).

Comment: What do you think the `EECDH+aRSA+RC4` and `RC4` entries in `SSLCipherSuite` do?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SSLEngine on
> SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
> SSLHonorCipherOrder on
>
> SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 \
> EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 \
> EECDH EDH+aRSA RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"
> ```

Ensure your `httpd.conf` or `ssl.conf` includes the following. It also adds the Strict Transport header.

```
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!MD5:!RC4

Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15552001; includeSubdomains;"
```

You should score an *A+* on the Qualys SSL Test. Here's [our Qualys scorecard](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=cryptopp.com) using the settings. Its hosted on a CentOS 7 VM, too.